# Use-cases for Streams in Scala

Tags: scala, stream, scala-collections

In Scala there is a Stream class that is very much like an iterator.  The topic [Difference between Iterator and Stream in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527962/difference-between-iterator-and-stream-in-scala) offers some insights into the similarities and differences between the two.

Seeing how to use a stream is pretty simple but I don't have very many **common** use-cases where I would use a stream instead of other artifacts.

The ideas I have right now:

- If you need to make use of an infinite series.  But this does not seem like a common use-case to me so it doesn't fit my criteria.  (Please correct me if it is common and I just have a blind spot)
- If you have a series of data where each element needs to be computed but that you may want to reuse several times.  This is weak because I could just load it into a list which is conceptually easier to follow for a large subset of the developer population.
- Perhaps there is a large set of data or a computationally expensive series and there is a high probability that the items you need will not require visiting all of the elements.  But in this case an Iterator would be a good match unless you need to do several searches, in that case you could use a list as well even if it would be slightly less efficient.
- There is a complex series of data that needs to be reused.  Again a list could be used here.  Although in this case both cases would be equally difficult to use and a Stream would be a better fit since not all elements need to be loaded.  But again not that common... or is it?

So have I missed any big uses?  Or is it a developer preference for the most part?

Thanks

Answer (score 41):

The main difference between a `Stream` and an `Iterator` is that the latter is mutable and "one-shot", so to speak, while the former is not. `Iterator` has a better memory footprint than `Stream`, but the fact that it *is* mutable can be inconvenient.

Take this classic prime number generator, for instance:

```
def primeStream(s: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] =
  Stream.cons(s.head, primeStream(s.tail filter { _ % s.head != 0 }))
val primes = primeStream(Stream.from(2))
```

It can be easily be written with an `Iterator` as well, but an `Iterator` won't *keep* the primes computed so far.

So, one important aspect of a `Stream` is that you can pass it to other functions without having it duplicated first, or having to generate it again and again.

As for expensive computations/infinite lists, these things can be done with `Iterator` as well. Infinite lists are actually quite useful -- you just don't know it because you didn't have it, so you have seen algorithms that are more complex than strictly necessary just to deal with enforced finite sizes.

Comment: Another difference which I'd like to add is that `Stream` is never lazy in its head element. The head of a `Stream` is stored in evaluated form. If one needs a sequence where no element (including the head) is computed until requested then `Iterator` is the only choice.

Comment: Besides it's non-laziness in head element, it also evaluates every element which you want to drop. e.g.: `"a"#::"b"#::"c"#::"d"#::Stream.empy[String].drop(3)` will evaluate "a", "b", "c" and "d" . "d" because it becomes head.

Comment: Interesting succinct example for the prime number generator. Interestingly, if I create that in a simple Scala console and then ask for 4000 primes (not that much in practice, I have an alternative definition that creates 100K in less than 2 seconds) it crashes Scala with a "GC overhead limit exceeded" error.

Answer (score 19):

In addition to Daniel's answer, keep in mind that `Stream` is useful for short-circuiting evaluations.  For example, suppose I have a huge set of functions that take `String` and return `Option[String]`, and I want to keep executing them until one of them works:

```
val stringOps = List(
  (s:String) => if (s.length>10) Some(s.length.toString) else None ,
  (s:String) => if (s.length==0) Some("empty") else None ,
  (s:String) => if (s.indexOf(" ")>=0) Some(s.trim) else None
);
```

Well, I certainly don't want to execute the *entire* list, and there isn't any handy method on `List` that says, "treat these as functions and execute them until one of them returns something other than `None`".  What to do?  Perhaps this:

```
def transform(input: String, ops: List[String=>Option[String]]) = {
  ops.toStream.map( _(input) ).find(_ isDefined).getOrElse(None)
}
```

This takes a list and treats it as a `Stream` (which doesn't actually evaluate anything), then defines a new `Stream` that is a result of applying the functions (but that doesn't evaluate anything either yet), then searches for the first one which is defined--and here, magically, it looks back and realizes it has to apply the map, and get the right data from the original list--and then unwraps it from `Option[Option[String]]` to `Option[String]` using `getOrElse`.

Here's an example:

```
scala> transform("This is a really long string",stringOps)
res0: Option[String] = Some(28)

scala> transform("",stringOps)
res1: Option[String] = Some(empty)

scala> transform("  hi ",stringOps)
res2: Option[String] = Some(hi)

scala> transform("no-match",stringOps)
res3: Option[String] = None
```

But does it work?  If we put a `println` into our functions so we can tell if they're called, we get

```
val stringOps = List(
  (s:String) => {println("1"); if (s.length>10) Some(s.length.toString) else None },
  (s:String) => {println("2"); if (s.length==0) Some("empty") else None },
  (s:String) => {println("3"); if (s.indexOf(" ")>=0) Some(s.trim) else None }
);
// (transform is the same)

scala> transform("This is a really long string",stringOps)
1
res0: Option[String] = Some(28)

scala> transform("no-match",stringOps)                    
1
2
3
res1: Option[String] = None
```

(This is with Scala 2.8; 2.7's implementation will sometimes overshoot by one, unfortunately.  And note that you *do* accumulate a long list of `None` as your failures accrue, but presumably this is inexpensive compared to your true computation here.)

Comment: I actually such an example, but this can just as easily be done with `Iterator`, so I decided it was beside the point.

Comment: Granted.  I should have clarified that this isn't Stream-specific, or picked an example that used multiple calls to the same Stream.

Answer (score 7):

I could imagine, that if you poll some device in real time, a Stream is more convenient.

Think of an GPS tracker, which returns the actual position if you ask it. You can't precompute the location where you will be in 5 minutes. You might use it for a few minutes only to actualize a path in OpenStreetMap or you might use it for an expedition over six months in a desert or the rain forest.

Or a digital thermometer or other kinds of sensors which repeatedly return new data, as long as the hardware is alive and turned on - a log file filter could be another example.

Answer (score 3):

`Stream` is to `Iterator` as `immutable.List` is to `mutable.List`. Favouring immutability prevents a class of bugs, occasionally at the cost of performance.

scalac itself isn't immune to these problems: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.internals/2831

As Daniel points out, favouring laziness over strictness can simplify algorithms and make it easier to compose them.

Comment: Of course, to those new to laziness, the major caveat is that it reduces predictability of the code, can lead to heisenbugs, and may have severe performance issues for some classes of algorithms.