# Best way to build and return a list from a method

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

Is there a Scala construct for building and returning a list like so?

```
def getOutput(isValidInput: Boolean): List[Output] =
  if (isValidInput) {
    yield Output(1) // Pseudo-code... I know yield is not intended for this!
    yield Output(2)
  }
```

Instead of...

```
def getOutput(isValidInput: Boolean): List[Output] =
  if (isValidInput)
    List(Output(1), Output(2))
  else
    Nil
```

In C# the use of 'yield' allows you to return lazy-evaluated collections - is there something similar in Scala?

Comment: The question is not clear to me if you want lazyness or conciseness of code. The List won't be created in your example unless the boolean is true.

Comment: What you want is a form of continuation. This is somewhat supported, but probably less readable than other options. See http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2096

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a lazy sequence, use a `Stream`:

```
case class Output(value: Int)

def getOutput(isValidInput: Boolean):Stream[Output] = getOutput(isValidInput, 1)

def getOutput(isValidInput: Boolean, index: Int):Stream[Output] =
  if (isValidInput && index < 3) {
    println("Index: " + index)
    Output(index) #:: getOutput(isValidInput, index+1)
  } else {
    Stream.empty[Output]
  }

println("Calling getOutput")
val result: Stream[Output] = getOutput(true)
println("Finished getOutput")

result foreach println
```

This results in:

```
Calling getOutput
Index: 1
Finished getOutput
Output(1)
Index: 2
Output(2)
```

If you want to keep the return type as `List[Output]`, using `yield` is a valid approach:

```
def getOutput(isValidInput: Boolean):List[Output] =
  if (isValidInput) {
    (for (i <- 1 until 3) yield Output(i))(collection.breakOut)
  } else {
    List.empty[Output]
  }
```

Also, using a `Vector` is often preferable over a `List`.

**Related:**

- [Scala 2.8 breakOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout/1716558#1716558)
- [What is Scala's yield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052476/what-is-scalas-yield)
- [When should I choose Vector in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928327/when-should-i-choose-vector-in-scala)
- [Use-cases for Streams in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096876/use-cases-for-streams-in-scala)