# Scala Unit type

Tags: scala, while-loop

I use opencsv to parse csv files, and my code is

```
while( (line = reader.readNext()) != null ) { .... }
```

I got a compiler warning saying:

```
 comparing values of types Unit and Null using `!=' will always yield true
 [warn]     while( (aLine = reader.readNext()) != null ) {
```

How should I do the while loop?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your case (line = reader.readNext()) is a functional literal that returns type Unit. You may rewrite the code as follows:

```
while( {line = reader.readNext();  line!= null} ) { .... }
```

Comment: Please do not accept this answer: whilst true it is not idiomatic Scala and there are much better ways of achieving what you want (see my answer below)

Comment: @oxbow_lakes, perhaps you are being a bit stern here? The while keyword is used hundreds of times in the 2.8 standard library by the core team and this answer is performant, concise and most importantly, looks like my answer too  ;@))

Comment: I stand by the comment, I'm afraid. This is not idiomatic. It's not even more performance than the *functional* answers because your code will get compiled to a function (i.e. object) instantiation

Answer (score 71):

An assignment expression has type `Unit` in Scala. That is the reason for your compiler warning.

There is a nice idiom in Scala that avoids the while loop:

```
val iterator = Iterator.continually(reader.readNext()).takeWhile(_ != null)
```

This gives you an iterator over whatever `reader.readNext` returns.

The `continually` method returns an "infinite" iterator and `takeWhile` takes the prefix of that, up to but not including the first null.

(Scala 2.8)

Comment: Hmm. My answer does not really match the question. I'll keep it, it might be useful anyway.

Comment: Why don't you think your answer matches the question?

Comment: @Ken: portoalet asked for an explanation for the warning about Unit. I answered with a loop idiom. I've just added the explanation for the warning to make the answer complete.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I was trying to figure out what it was about your code that *didn't* do the same thing as his while loop. Since it does the same thing, the reason your answer didn't match the question is because it didn't talk about the warning.

Comment: and how I execute code "inside" `iterator`? Like I'd execute it "inside" while loop.

Comment: Is it worth pointing out that this `Iterator` will not evaluate eagerly, unlike the `while` block will _execute_ eagerly?

Answer (score 18):

You can use a `Stream` to get what you want:

```
Stream.continually(reader.readLine()).takeWhile( _ ne null) foreach { line =>
  //do Stuff
}
```

This has the added advantage of other cool stuff as well:

```
Stream.continually(reader.readLine()).takeWhile( _ ne null) match {
  case head #:: tail => //perhaps you need to do stuff with the first element?
  case _             => //empty
}
```

**EDIT** - *thanks to mkneissl for pointing out I should have included this warning*:

```
scala> Stream.continually(1).take(100000000).foreach(x=>()) 

scala> val s = Stream.continually(1).take(100000000) 
s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?) 

scala> s.foreach(x=>()) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: You might want to add a warning not to keep the head of the Stream to avoid running out of memory. Have been caught by this recently when reading huge files.

scala> Stream.continually(1).take(100000000).foreach(x=>())

is ok, but

scala> val s = Stream.continually(1).take(100000000)
s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> s.foreach(x=>())
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[ bah, no formatting in comments, see pastie: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/226682/ ]

Comment: Unless you actually need a Stream, you might as well use Iterator.continually instead of Stream.continually, then you have no worries about problems with Stream.

Comment: Right Seth, see my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062804/scala-unit-type/3063092#3063092 and for a comparison of Stream vs. Iterator see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527962/difference-between-iterator-and-stream-in-scala .

Comment: @mkneissl not sure I understand why the OOM error would happen, could you elaborate on the OOM issue?

Comment: @MehdiB. , see https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html :
"""One must be cautious of memoization; you can very quickly eat up large amounts of memory if you're not careful. The reason for this is that the memoization of the Stream creates a structure much like scala.collection.immutable.List. So long as something is holding on to the head, the head holds on to the tail, and so it continues recursively."""

Answer (score 10):

You are writing Scala code they way you would write it in Java. Try doing it in a more Scala-like way. To read a text file line by line and do something with each line, try this:

```
import java.io.File
import scala.io.Source

Source.fromFile(new File("myfile.txt")).getLines.foreach { line =>
    // Do something with the line, for example print it
    println(line)
}
```

Comment: He's not doing plain file IO. He's doing CSV IO.

Comment: @Ken CSV files are normally line-oriented text files, and his code snippet above is about reading a text file line by line. My answer indeed isn't a direct answer to his question, I just wanted to show a way that fits more with the Scala idiom; his original code is Java idiom in Scala.

Answer (score 3):

Assignment in Scala doesn't return a value, Unit is similar to void in C or C++.

try

```
var line = ""

while ({line = reader.readNext(); line != null}) { ... }
```

This works because the value of the last expression in a block is returned and in this case it is a Boolean which is required by the **while**

Comment: `Unit` in Scala is more similar to `void` than to `null`.