# Infinite loop seems to confuse Scala's type system

Tags: scala, infinite-loop, type-inference, return-type

Here is an artificial toy example that demonstrates my problem:

```
def sscce(): Int = {
  val rand = new Random()
  var count = 0
  while (true) {   // type mismatch; found: Unit, required: Int
    count += 1
    if (rand.nextInt() == 42) return count
  }
}
```

How can I help the compiler understand that this method will always return an `Int`?

I know the above toy example could easily be refactored to get rid of the infinite loop altogether, but I *really* want to have the infinite loop in my actual code. Trust me on this ;)

Comment: Your code doesn't, technically speaking, return an Int. It returns an Int *if* the function returns at all. I suspect this distinction is the problem. What are you trying to solve? You say you really want an infinite loop, but perhaps your real world problem can have another solution.

Comment: I really love infinite loops, but they take forever to finish.

Comment: You can't prove that it will always be executed because it won't always be executed. It will usually be executed, but scala doesn't provide a `Usually[Int]` type. I'd be shocked if there wasn't a better way to do this instead of using the infinite loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala while(true) type mismatch? Infinite loop in scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802917/scala-whiletrue-type-mismatch-infinite-loop-in-scala)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do:

```
def foo: Int = {
  ...
  while(true) {
    ... return ...
  }
  throw new IllegalStateException  // unreachable
}
```

this will typecheck because the type of the `throw` is `Nothing`, which is a subtype of `Int`.

Answer (score 6):

Always return an `Int`:

```
def sscce(): Int = {
  val rand = new Random()
  var count = 0
  while (true) {
    count += 1
    if (rand.nextInt() == 42) return count
  }
  count // <-- this
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785965/scala-while-loop-returns-unit-all-the-time). While loops don't return a value. i.e. they return `Unit` which is the last statement in your function. So, the definition says it returns an `Int` but it actually returns `Unit` thus the type error. @ionut's answer fixes the type error by returning `count` as the last statement or here is a recursive approach.

```
def sscce(): Int = {
  val rand = new Random()
  def ssccer(count: Int): Int = {
    if(rand.nextInt == 42) return count
    else ssccer(count + 1)
  }
  ssccer(0)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Per the [SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#while-loop-expressions), a `while` loop is executed similarly to:

```
def whileLoop(cond: => Boolean)(body: => Unit): Unit  =
  if (cond) { body ; whileLoop(cond)(body) } else {}
```

ie., it returns `Unit`. So the compiler sees the `while` as the last statement in `sscce()`, and therefore assumes that you're trying to return `Unit`. I don't think it's smart enough to realize that `return count` will *eventually* always return an `Int`.

The simple solution is to follow the suggestion of @Brian or @IonutGStan, and force it to return `count`, whether it truly needs it or not.

Answer (score 2):

From a code quality standpoint, it would be good to ditch the `while(true)` loop and replace it with something more readable. As a nice side effect, it also solves your problem:

```
def sscce(): Int = {
  val rand = new Random()
  var count = 1
  while (rand.nextInt() != 42) {
    count += 1
  }
  count
}
```