# Scala tail-recursive Stream processor function defined in trait holds reference to stream-head

Tags: scala, stream, functional-programming

In the following situation

```
trait T {

 @tailrec
 def consume[A](as: Stream[A]): Unit = {
    if (as.isEmpty) ()
    else consume(as.tail)
  }
 }

object O extends T
```

calling `O.consume(Range(1, N).toStream)` with `N` big enough, the program will run out of memory, or at least will consume O(N) instead of the needed O(1).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529697/how-to-write-non-leaking-tail-recursive-stream-function-in-scala

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tail-recursive method is generated for the trait. The method entry in the extender of the trait (here `O`) forwards the call to the method of the trait, but while doing so, it keeps a reference to the head of the Stream.

Thus the method is tail-recursive, but memory still can't be released. Remedy: Don't define Stream functions in traits, just directly in objects.

An alternative is scalaz's [`EphemeralStream`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/EphemeralStream.scala), which holds weak references to the stream head and tail, and recomputes them on demand.

Comment: [EphemeralStream](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/EphemeralStream.scala)

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple workaround. Just wrap your tail recursive stream consumer in another function that receives the stream via a by-name parameter:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

trait T {
  def consume[A](as: => Stream[A]): Unit = {
    @tailrec
    def loop[A](as: Stream[A]): Unit = {
        if (as.isEmpty) ()
       else loop(as.tail)
    }
    loop(as)
  }
}

object O extends T {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = 
    O.consume(Range(1, 1000000000).toStream) 
}
```

The forwarder method will hold a reference to a *function* computing an expression the   result of which is a stream:

```
public final class O$ implements T {
  public static final MODULE$;
  // This is the forwarder:
  public <A> void consume(Function0<Stream<A>> as) {
    T.class.consume(this, as);
  }
     .  .  .      

  public void main(String[] args) {
    consume(new AbstractFunction0() {
      public final Stream<Object> apply() {
        return package..MODULE$.Range().apply(1, 1000000000).toStream();
      }
    });
  }
}
```