# How to write non-leaking tail-recursive function using Stream.cons in Scala?

Tags: scala, recursion, memory-leaks, stream

When writing a function operating on `Stream`(s), there are different notions of recursion. The first simple sense is not recursive on the compiler level, since the tail if not evaluated instantly so the function returns immediately, but the returned stream is recursive:

```
final def simpleRec[A](as: Stream[A]): Stream[B] = 
  if (a.isEmpty) Stream.empty              
  else someB(a.head) #:: simpleRec(a.tail)
```

The above notion of recursion doesn't cause any problems. The second one is truly tail-recursive on the compiler level:

```
@tailrec
final def rec[A](as: Stream[A]): Stream[B] = 
  if (a.isEmpty) Stream.empty              // A) degenerated
  else if (someCond) rec(a.tail)           // B) tail recursion
  else someB(a.head) #:: rec(a.tail)       // C) degenerated
```

The problem here is that the `C)` case is detected by the compiler as a non-tailrec call, even if there is no actual call carried out. This can be avoided by factoring out the stream tail into a helper function:

```
@tailrec
final def rec[A](as: Stream[A]): Stream[B] = 
  if (a.isEmpty) Stream.empty              
  else if (someCond) rec(a.tail)          // B)
  else someB(a.head) #:: recHelp(a.tail)  

@tailrec
final def recHelp[A](as: Stream[A]): Stream[B] = 
  rec(as)
```

While it compiles, this approach eventually results in a memory leak. Since the tail-recursive `rec` is eventually called from the `recHelp` function, the stack frame of the `recHelp` function holds a reference to the steam head, and doesn't let the stream to be garbage collected until the `rec` call returns, which can quite long (in terms of recursion steps) depending on the number of calls to `B)`.

Note that even in the helperless case, if the compiler allowed the @tailrec, the memory leak may still be present since the lazy stream tail would in effect create an anonymous object holding reference to the stream head.

Comment: Also see the related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486762/scala-tail-recursive-stream-processor-function-defined-in-trait-holds-reference

Comment: any chance of a working piece of code?  I.e. one that OOMs?

Comment: Chris: sure, compare the two: https://gist.github.com/3769565 (2.10.0-M7 doesn't oom for ok.scala)

Comment: Thanks, I finally got the time to look at it, as per your answer you only need to keep one reference around and the whole stream is kept in memory.

Comment: You should try passing the stream by reference to the helper as in `final def recHelp[A](as: => Stream[A]): Stream[B]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as you've hinted, is that in the code you pasted the filterHelp function keeps the head (hence your solution removing it).

Best answer is to simply avoid this surprising behaviour, use Scalaz EphemeralStream and see it both not oom and run significantly faster as its far nicer to the gc.  Its not always as simple to work with e.g. head is a () => A not A, no extractors etc, but its all geared to one objective, reliable stream usage.

Your filterHelper function generally doesn't have to care about if it keeps a reference around:

```
import scalaz.EphemeralStream

@scala.annotation.tailrec
def filter[A](s: EphemeralStream[A], f: A => Boolean): EphemeralStream[A] = 
  if (s.isEmpty) 
    s
  else
    if (f(s.head())) 
      EphemeralStream.cons(s.head(), filterHelp(s.tail() , f) )
    else
      filter(s.tail(), f)

def filterHelp[A](s: EphemeralStream[A], f: A => Boolean) =
  filter(s, f)

def s1 = EphemeralStream.range(1, big)
```

I'd go so far as to say that unless you have a compelling reason to use Stream (other library dependencies etc) then just stick to EphemeralStream, there are far less surprises there.

Comment: ES is a good point. I needed Stream because the underlying source is not a computation but a mutable iterator. I know I'd be better off using Iteratees (or the like, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496654/is-there-an-iteratee-like-concept-which-pulls-data-from-multiple-sources).

Answer (score 3):

A possible workaround is to make the `recHelp` method not hold reference to the stream head. This can be achieved by passing a wrapped stream to it, and mutating the wrapper to erase the reference from it:

```
@tailrec
final def rec[A](as: Stream[A]): Stream[B] = 
  if (a.isEmpty) Stream.empty              
  else if (someCond) rec(a.tail)          
  else {
    // don't inline and don't define as def,
    // or anonymous lazy wrapper object would hold reference
    val tailRef = new AtomicReference(a.tail)
    someB(a.head) #:: recHelp(tailRef)  
  }

@tailrec
final def recHelp[A](asRef: AtomicReference[Stream[A]]): Stream[B] = 
  // Note: don't put the content of the holder into a local variable
  rec(asRef.getAndSet(null))
```

The `AtomicReference` is just convenience, atomicity is not required in this case, any simple holder object would do.

Also note that since `recHelp` is wrapped in a stream `Cons` tail, therefore it will only be evaluated once, and `Cons` also takes care of synchronization.