# Is there an Iteratee-like concept which pulls data from multiple sources?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, loops

It is possible to pull on demand from a number (say two for simplicity) of sources using streams (lazy lists). Iteratees can be used to process data coming from a single source.

Is there an Iteratee-like functional concept for processing multiple input sources? I could imagine an Iteratee whose state signals from which source does it want to pull.

Comment: so you have two sources and you want to get events from whichever has them available first?

Comment: Any way of pulling from multiple sources is probably going to be equivalent to some way of combining two sources into one. There are many ways this could be done; could you clarify what behavior you're looking for?

Comment: I thought about something general, where the sink can control based on state which source to pull. The specific scenario would be to merge two sorted streams, so I get tuples where the keys of elements equal, and unpairable elements get dropped.

Comment: Any iteratee library can do this by simply stacking monads.  Oleg showed how first (http://okmij.org/ftp/Streams.html#2enum1iter).  I've used this with my own iteratee package.  It'll work with any of them.

Comment: @John: Thanks! By the way I recall having already heard the phrase "Oleg showed first" :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To do this using pipes you nest the Pipe monad transformer within itself, once for each producer you wish to interact with.  For example:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Pipe

producerA, producerB :: (Monad m) => Producer Int m ()
producerA = mapM_ yield [1,2,3]
producerB = mapM_ yield [4,5,6]

consumes2 :: (Show a, Show b) =>
    Consumer a (Consumer b IO) r
consumes2 = forever $ do
    a <- await       -- await from outer producer
    b <- lift await  -- await from inner producer
    lift $ lift $ print (a, b)
```

Just like a Haskell curried function of multiple variables, you partially apply it to each source using composition and  runPipe:

```
consumes1 :: (Show b) => Consumer b IO ()
consumes1 = runPipe $ consumes2 <+< producerA

fullyApplied :: IO ()
fullyApplied = runPipe $ consumes1 <+< producerB
```

The above function outputs when run:

```
>>> fullyApplied
(1, 4)
(2, 5)
(3, 6)
```

This trick works for yielding or awaiting to any number of pipes upstream or downstream.  It also works for proxies, the bidirectional analogs to pipes.

Edit: Note that this also works for any iteratee library, not just `pipes`.  In fact, John Milikin and Oleg were the original advocates for this approach and I just stole the idea from them.

Comment: I'd just like to note that this works with every other iteratee package, not just pipes.

Answer (score 6):

We're using [Machines](http://github.com/runarorama/scala-machines) in Scala to pull in not just two, but an arbitrary amount of sources.

Two examples of binary joins are provided by the library itself, on the `Tee` module: `mergeOuterJoin` and `hashJoin`. Here is what the code for `hashJoin` looks like (it assumes both streams are sorted):

```
/**
 * A natural hash join according to keys of type `K`.
 */
def hashJoin[A, B, K](f: A => K, g: B => K): Tee[A, B, (A, B)] = {
  def build(m: Map[K, A]): Plan[T[A, B], Nothing, Map[K, A]] = (for {
    a  <- awaits(left[A])
    mp <- build(m + (f(a) -> a))
  } yield mp) orElse Return(m)
  for {
    m <- build(Map())
    r <- (awaits(right[B]) flatMap (b => {
      val k = g(b)
      if (m contains k) emit(m(k) -> b) else Return(())
    })) repeatedly
  } yield r
}
```

This code builds up a `Plan` which is "compiled" to a `Machine` with the `repeatedly` method. The type being built here is `Tee[A, B, (A, B)]` which is a machine with two inputs. You request inputs on the left and right with `awaits(left)` and `awaits(right)`, and you output with `emit`.

There is also a [Haskell version of Machines](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines).

Answer (score 3):

Conduits (and, it can be built for Pipes, but that code hasn't been released yet) has a `zip` primitive that takes two upstreams and combines them as a stream of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [pipes library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-2.3.0), where [vertical concatenation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/2.3.0/doc/html/Control-Pipe-Tutorial.html#g:4) might do what you want.  For example,

```
import Control.Pipe
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Void

source0, source1 :: Producer Char IO ()
source0 = mapM_ yield "say"
source1 = mapM_ yield "what"

sink :: Show b => Consumer b IO ()
sink = forever $ await >>= \x -> lift $ print x

pipeline :: Pipe () Void IO ()
pipeline = sink <+< (source0 >> source1)
```

The sequencing operator `(>>)` vertically concatenates the sources, yielding the output (on a `runPipe`)

```
's'
'a'
'y'
'w'
'h'
'a'
't'
```