# Scala Stream "isEmpty" method VS pattern matching "head #:: tail"

Tags: scala, stream, is-empty

When I debug, it shows "$Stream$Empty". But it didn't fall into .isEmpty case. I changed the pattern to "head #:: tail", it's working fine against some test cases. Could anyone explain what's happened behind the scenes?

Comment: You need to show actual code.

Comment: speculation: The stream is non empty in the sense that it has elements but non of these elements are realized yet.

Comment: :( The codes are related to assignment from Functional Programming course in Coursera.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Iterator and Stream in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527962/difference-between-iterator-and-stream-in-scala)

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful? isEmpty works great.

```
val strm = true #:: false #:: Stream[Boolean]()
def matchStream[T](stream:Stream[T]):List[String] = {
  stream match {
    case head #:: tail => head.toString :: matchStream(tail)
    case stm if stm.isEmpty => List("end of stream")
  }
}
matchStream(strm)
```

I ran this in a worksheet and got

```
res0: List[String] = List(true, false, end of stream)
```

Comment: This is a 3 year old question about debugger output, which your answer doesn't address. I doubt the OP (who hasn't visited SO in over a year) or anyone else is going to find this helpful.