# A simple scala code for mapping a list to list elements order. (For generating line numbers)

Tags: scala

I have simple scala code :

```
object CollectionSnippets extends App {

  var closureVal = 0 
  def lineNum(s:String) : String = {
    closureVal = closureVal + 1;
    closureVal.toString + "." + s;
  }
  val list1 = List("aline","aline","aline")

  val list2 = list1.map(lineNum)

  list2.foreach(println)

}
```

The problem is I am mutating a variable and I sense that this is not the right thing to do.

Could you suggest me a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `zipWithIndex`.

```
scala> list1.zipWithIndex.map(t => t._2 + ": " + t._1)
res0: List[String] = List(0: aline, 1: aline, 2: aline)

scala> res0.foreach(println(_))
0: aline
1: aline
2: aline
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider this,

```
list1 zip Stream.from(1) foreach { x => println(x._2 + "." + x._1) }
```

Yet for neat integration consider

```
implicit class RichLiner[A](val a: List[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def liner(sep: String = ".") = 
    a zip Stream.from(1) foreach { x => println(x._2 + sep + x._1) } 
}
```

and so

```
scala> list1.liner()
1.aline
2.aline
3.aline
```

**Update**

A best option is to use `Iterator.from(1)` (note comments and idea thanks to @om-nom-nom), for instance as follows,

```
list1.iterator zip Iterator.from(1) foreach { it => println(it._2 + "." + it._1) }

1.aline
2.aline
3.aline
```

Comment: Why do you use Stream?

Comment: @om-nom-nom good question, first thought that came to mind, perhaps because initial value can be chosen; otherwise no strong criteria for opting for Stream.

Comment: I would prefer `Iterator.from(1)`

Comment: @om-nom-nom ok :) didn't know of it, what are the differences/benefits wrt Stream.from ? thx

Comment: Stream is a more heavyweight approach -- it may [persist elements into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527962/difference-between-iterator-and-stream-in-scala) plus it's implemented in quite [clumsy way](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.1/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.scala#L1107)